# If Checkbox checked, only allow the next Checkbox to check

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I make a Table with php function

```
<table width='400' border='0' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0' id='booking'>
<tr>
    <th width='150' align='left'>Start</th>
    <th width='150' align='left'>End</th>
    <th width='150' align='left'></th>
    <th width='20' align='left'>reserv</th>         
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

At the end i make td's with times and dates. in the last is one checkbox.

This i make around 10 times:

```
<tr>
    <td>" . $start . "</td>\r\n
    <td>" . date("H:i:s", $finish_time) . "</td>\r\n
    <td>" . $this->cost_currency_tag . number_format($this->cost_per_slot, 2) . "</td>
    <td width='110'>
        <input data-val='".$start."-".date("H:i:s", $finish_time)."' class='fields' type='checkbox'>
    </td>
</tr>";
```

I will make when i check a checkbox jquery allow only to check the NEXT checkbox. all other disabled. And when i check the next, it must be allow to check the next of this.

I have tried with this

```
$('.fields input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    var obj = $(this).siblings('input[type=text]');
    obj.attr('disabled', !obj.attr('disabled'));
})
```

But i do not get it work.. i have tried also with '.next'...
Can anyone help?

Comment: Clarify exactly what this means: "This i make 10 times" - I'm not sure which part you do 10 times.  Post the full HTML

Comment: i hope this is better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code

```js
$(".fields").change(function(){
    var index = $(this).index() + 1;
    $(".fields").attr("disabled", true);  
    $(".fields:lt("+ index +")").attr("disabled", false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="fields" />
<input type="checkbox" class="fields" />
<input type="checkbox" class="fields" />
<input type="checkbox" class="fields" />
<input type="checkbox" class="fields" />
```

Comment: thanks, i have tried it, but now only the first checkbox is allowed to check all other where disabled

Comment: @joergi1988 But it work in snippet. It doesn't work in your local?

Comment: @joergi1988 If it disabled all checkbox on your code, you can use `var index = $(this).index() + 2` instead. Like [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/do4290pg/)

Comment: on lokal it doesn't work. also i have tried +2. Anything i check, it allows only the first, and with +2 the first and the next to the first <- anything i check.

Comment: @joergi1988 Now is there any problem?

Comment: no, it show nothing problems. but when i cklick on a checkbox it allows the first checkbox in table to check and all other disabled, wherever i click

Comment: @joergi1988 See [**example**](https://jsfiddle.net/do4290pg/1/) to use `input` in `table`.

Comment: @joergi1988 When you changed html, you need to change jquery to relevant selector. See https://jsfiddle.net/9n1rusLy/1/

Comment: Thanks. that is great. but in my lokal i tried, if i check any checkbox it disabled all :-( .. i dont know whats this... i search a little bit...

Comment: YES i have it... i have changed the last line to $("tr .fields:lt("+index+")").attr("disabled", false);.... now it work perfectly!!! THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

[Mohammad's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38014481/3078890) answer seems to be incorrect.
You can check some of checkboxes and then remove check from one not the last checked to see what would be the problem.

---

Here but when you uncheck a checkbox then all checkboxes after that will become disabeld.

If you want to uncheck the remaining as well then use the commented section.

```js
var fields = $(".fields");
fields.change(function() {
  Array.prototype.reduce.call(fields, function(prev, curr) {
    curr.disabled = !prev.checked || prev.disabled;

    /*
      If you want to uncheck remianing use this instead of above line:
      curr.checked = prev.checked ? curr.checked : false;
      curr.disabled = !prev.checked;
    */
    return curr;
  });
});

fields.change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="fields" /> check box</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="fields" /> check box</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="fields" /> check box</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="fields" /> check box</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="fields" /> check box</label><br/>
```

Comment: thats nice! but how can i change this code to -> i like to check any checkbox and with this only the first i can check?

Comment: I didn't get what you want; can you explain more. Do you mean to start from anywhere and then the conditions applies from that forward?(all checkboxes before that become disabled.)

Comment: no, all checkboxes at start are enabled. and start from anywhere. and then only up or down one checkbox... that is what i want to work :-(

Comment: @joergi1988 I think I find your answer [check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gigapedia/9n1rusLy/2/). If so inform me to add it as an answer here.

Comment: @joergi1988 Did you find your answer? none of these would be the answer?[this](https://jsfiddle.net/Gigapedia/9n1rusLy/3/) or [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Gigapedia/9n1rusLy/2/).

Answer (score 1):

Finally the correct answer comes up (seems to be the selected one :)):

```js
$("tr .fields").change(function() {
  console.clear();
  $('.fields').attr('disabled', false);
  var checkedItems = $(".fields:checked");
  if (!checkedItems.length)
    return;
  var checkedIndices = checkedItems.map(function() {
    return $(this).closest('tr').index();
  });
  var lastInRow = Array.prototype.reduce
    .call(checkedIndices, function(p, c) {
      return (c > p + 1) ? p : c;
    });
  $("tr:gt(" + (lastInRow + 1) + ") .fields")
    .attr("disabled", true);

  /* If you wnat to disable items before last check you can add this*/
  // $("tr:lt(" + (lastInRow) + ") .fields").attr("disabled", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="8em">
      <input class='fields' type='checkbox'>
    </td>
    <td>This</td>
    <td>is a</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="8em">
      <input class='fields' type='checkbox'>
    </td>
    <td>This</td>
    <td>is a</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="8em">
      <input class='fields' type='checkbox'>
    </td>
    <td>This</td>
    <td>is a</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="8em">
      <input class='fields' type='checkbox'>
    </td>
    <td>This</td>
    <td>is a</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="8em">
      <input class='fields' type='checkbox'>
    </td>
    <td>This</td>
    <td>is a</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="8em">
      <input class='fields' type='checkbox'>
    </td>
    <td>This</td>
    <td>is a</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="8em">
      <input class='fields' type='checkbox'>
    </td>
    <td>This</td>
    <td>is a</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="8em">
      <input class='fields' type='checkbox'>
    </td>
    <td>This</td>
    <td>is a</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="8em">
      <input class='fields' type='checkbox'>
    </td>
    <td>This</td>
    <td>is a</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```